# Disable colorization for any other editor but Java in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse, how do I disable the custom theme colours for everything else other than Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a file with the text editor (without syntax highlighting) if you choose "open with -> text editor" in the contextual menu of the file. Your choice will be remembered by Eclipse the next time you'll open that file.

To change the default editor for a type of file, it's possible in the Eclise preferencves (in "File Associations").